# Найти среднее значение столбцов матрицы

Tags: c++, массивы

Дана матрица А(n,m). Сформировать массив В(m), каждый элемент которого есть среднее арифметическое значение соответствующего столбца матрицы А.

---

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(0,"RUS");
    const int n=3, m=4;
    int arr_A[3][4]={};
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
                arr_A[i][j]=rand()%50;

            }
    }
                for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            cout <<" "<< arr_A[i][j];
            }
            cout <<endl;
        }
            int sum=0;
        int arr_B[m]={};
            for(int l=0; l<n; l++){
                for(int v=0; v<m; v++){
```

Comment: А проблема в чем?

Comment: Действительно, легкая. В чем ваш вопрос-то?

Comment: Напишите код пожалуйста вот где я застрял сейчас

Comment: int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{setlocale(0,"RUS");
 const int n=3, m=4;
 int arr_A[3][4]={};
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
    arr_A[i][j]=rand()%50;
 
   }
 }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
     for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
   cout <<" "<< arr_A[i][j];
   }
   cout <<endl;
  }
   int sum=0;
  int arr_B[m]={};
   for(int l=0; l<n; l++){
    for(int v=0; v<m; v++){

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int col = 0; col < m; ++col)
{
    B[col] = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < n; ++row) B[col] += A[row][col];
    B[col] /= n;
}
```

Comment: Не братан не понял  в массив В нужно написать средне-арифметическое из столбцов массива А !!!

Comment: Ну, бро, в натуре заколебал... А я что сделал?

Comment: Да неправильные цифры показывает где надо исправил я все равно(((

Comment: Может, деление целочисленное использовано? Вместо с плавающей точкой?

Comment: @Harry: Нечего потакать халявщикам.